# Dialogflow returning answers with confidence score below ml classification threshold

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm training a chatbot using dialogflow and I've put the ml threshold classification as 0.7 but the ai is still detecting false positives when the confidence score comes below the classification threshold. Is this a bug or did I misunderstand how the ml threshold works?